# Is asking a question in the form 'What that impression might be?' acceptable?

Tags: grammar, questions

Someone wrote to me - Because you have an impression of me that's not true maybe.
I responded What that impression might be?
Is that acceptable or not?

Comment: You wouldn't phrase a question like that; you would say `"What might that impression be?"` However, you could say it your way if the phrase were the object of a sentence: `"I don't know what that impression might be."`

Comment: Consider checking out our sister site, http://ell.stackexchange.com .

Comment: You can't construct a sentence that way. But you can construct a subordinate clause that way. That clause would be a good direct object for _Do you know .._ and that would work as a question: _Do you know what that impression might be?_ (This is all assuming, of course, that what  "that impression" means is present in the previous context and understood by all parties. Otherwise, back to square one.)

Comment: Hello, anna85. I reworded your question heading in an effort to make it more meaningful to other site users who may be interested in the same question. A major goal of English Language & Usage is to ask and answer questions in a way that is accessible and meaningful to future users, not just to the person who had the question originally. Thanks!

Comment: How about...And what might that impression be?..

Answer (score 5):

In English, *[word order](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_order#Functions_of_constituent_word_order)* affects the meaning of a sentence. When asking a question, the understood constituent order is generally:

> {[Interrogative](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interrogative_word)} [[Auxiliary](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Auxiliary_verb)] <[Subject](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subject_(grammar))> ([Verb](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Verb))?

1. There can be other constituents in more complex questions, but for the purpose of your post, **one** correct word order would be:

> {What} [might] <*that impression*> (be)?

2. Because *what* functions as a [relative pronoun](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relative_pronoun) as well as an *interrogative pronoun*, the word order you presented marks it as a [relative clause](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relative_clause), which could be part of a more complex sentence:

> I don't know what that impression might be.

3. You could also use that relative clause as part of a more complex question without the interrogative:

> [Can] <*you*> (tell) |me| ***what that impression might be***?

4. Finally, *what* can also function as an [interrogative determiner](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_determiners#Common_determiners) followed by a noun to form another legitimate question:

> {What impression} [might] <*that*> (be)?

**Conclusion:**

To reply to your friend you could easily choose between the three questions:

> What might that impression be?
>   Can you tell me what that impression might be?
>   What impression might that be?

Comment: Would that conclusion be a choice between three questions?